# Spark saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile works on local mode but not on Cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, cloudera, spark-streaming

After upgrading to CDH5.4 and Spark streaming 1.3, I'm encountering a strange issue where saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile is no longer saving files to HDFS as it's suppose to. I can see that the _temp directory being generated, but when the Save is complete, the _temp is removed and leaving the directory empty with just a SUCCESS file. I have a feeling that the files are generated but afterward, they were unable to be moved out of the _temp directory before _temp is deleted.

This issue only happen when running on the Spark Cluster (standalone mode). If I run the job with local spark, files are saved as expected.

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  I'm having the same issue.

Comment: hi, no unfortunately. but we did find a workaround, basically configured our spark cluster to YARN and updated our spark jobs accordingly.

Comment: Hello @DiWu, please let us know how you solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on your laptop/desktop?

One way this can happen is if the path you use for your output is a *relative* path on NFS. In that case, Spark assumes relative paths are hdfs:// not file:// and can't write out to disk.